# Different outputs when using "this" with arrow operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider for example

```
const myObject = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: {
         foo: 'bar',
         baz: function () { console.log( this.foo ) },
    }
};

myObject.bar.baz(); // Prints 'bar'
```

Whereas with arrow operator it produces

```
const myObject = {
     foo: 'foo',
     bar: {
          foo: 'bar',
          baz: () => console.log( this.foo ),
     }
};
myObject.bar.baz(); // Prints 'undefined'
```

Can anyone please explain why behaviour is different ?

I know that arrow functions are lexically scoped, but unable to understand reference to `this`

Comment: Arrow functions use the value of `this` at the time they were created, not when they're called.

Comment: makes sense. Please post comment as answer.

Comment: See also: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)

Comment: Can't answer a closed question.